# How can I apply the same event listener used for all elements on form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, addeventlistener

Here's my sample JS code:

```
function createListener(input) {
  return (e)=> {
    const el=e.target;
    const inputValue=e.target.value;
    const validator=inputCheck(input)
    const valid=validator(inputValue);
    borderHighlight(valid, el)
  }
}

inputs.forEach(input=> {
  input.addEventListener("input", createListener(input))
})


function borderHighlight(valid, el) {
  (valid)? el.style.border='2px solid green':el.style.border='2px solid red'
}

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault()
  inputs.forEach(input=> {
    createListener(input)
  })
})
```

The input event listener on each element is perfect for what it does. It gives live error messages as the user inputs. But I want that function to do the same thing when the user submits the form as well (on the submit event attached to the form element)? How can I implement that functionality in my code?

Comment: `createListener(input)` returns a function that takes a javascript event as a parameter in order to get the appropriate element.  You don't really have that event when you're submitting the form so much of the createListener returned function won't work as is, I'd suggest you create a similar function that accepts an element as a parameter rather than an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the validation code in a named function, so you can call it from both event listeners.

```
function validate_input(el) {
    const inputValue=el.value;
    const validator=inputCheck(el)
    if (validator) {
        const valid= validator(inputValue);
        borderHighlight(valid, el);
    }
}

function createListener(input) {
    return e => validate_input(input);
}

inputs.forEach(input=> {
  input.addEventListener("input", createListener(input))
})


function borderHighlight(valid, el) {
  (valid)? el.style.border='2px solid green':el.style.border='2px solid red'
}

myform.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  inputs.forEach(input => validate_input(input));
});
```

Comment: My habitual style is underscores rather than camelCase.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your `inputCheck()` function, it's supposed to return a validator function.

Comment: Since you didn't post `inputCheck()` I don't know why that's not working.

Comment: `inputs` includes the `submit` button, but `inputCheck()` doesn't handle that case.

Comment: I added a conditional test for `validator`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the form submit listener a bit. Call the function returned from `createListener` and pass a fake event object: `{target: input}`.

```
myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault()
  inputs.forEach(input=> {
    createListener(input)({target: input});
  })
});
```

This way you don't need to change anything within `createListener`.

Comment: This will add additional listeners to each input when the user submits the form.

Comment: @Barmar Nope, the listeners are attached in a separate `forEach` loop, the function name is confusing, though.

Comment: Right, I was thinking that `createListener` calls `addEventListener`.